# Скрыть возраст домена

Tags: whois

Как можно скрыть дату создания домена? И реально ли это

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: смотря где.... вон на nic.ru за отдельную плату можно скрыть все данные о владельце

Comment: Мне нужно скрыть только дату создания. А данные о владельце оставить

Comment: можно вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Делаю игровой сайт, нормальный, а через всякие проверки на вирусность, идёт типо плохой, из-за того что он сделан не давно

Comment: С чего ты решил, что это именно из-за того, что сделан недавно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну сам подумай, а из-за чего же еще???

Comment: Там пишется на сайте мол регистрация больше 6 месяцев должна быть, просто видел там один сайт на котором дата регистрации не отображалась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Запрещено скрывать дату регистрации домена**

Дата регистрации домена не может быть изменена или скрыта в связи с политикой **ICANN**. Все регистраторы доменных имен обязаны соблюдать положение [ICANN WHOIS Accuracy](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois-accuracy), которое требует предоставлять публичный доступ к дате регистрации домена, дате окончания регистрации и т.д. Эта информация должна быть достоверной на протяжении всего периода регистрации домена.

**Краткая выдержка из положения [ICANN WHOIS Accuracy](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois-accuracy):**

> 3.3 Public Access to Data on Registered Names. During the Term of this Agreement:
>
> 3.3.1 At its expense, Registrar shall provide an interactive web page and, with respect to any gTLD operating a "thin" registry, a port 43
> Whois service (each accessible via both IPv4 and IPv6) providing free
> public query-based access to up-to-date (i.e., updated at least daily)
> data concerning all active Registered Names sponsored by Registrar in
> any gTLD. Until otherwise specified by a Consensus Policy, such data
> shall consist of the following elements as contained in Registrar's
> database:
>
> 3.3.1.1 The name of the Registered Name;
>
> 3.3.1.2 The names of the primary nameserver and secondary nameserver(s) for the Registered Name;
>
> 3.3.1.3 The identity of Registrar (which may be provided through Registrar's website);
>
> 3.3.1.4 The original creation date of the registration;
>
> 3.3.1.5 The expiration date of the registration;
>
> 3.3.1.6 The name and postal address of the Registered Name Holder;
>
> 3.3.1.7 The name, postal address, e-mail address, voice telephone number, and (where available) fax number of the technical contact for
> the Registered Name; and
>
> 3.3.1.8 The name, postal address, e-mail address, voice telephone number, and (where available) fax number of the administrative contact
> for the Registered Name.

**ICANN? Что это?**

> «Корпорация по управлению доменными именами и IP-адресами» (Internet
> Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers), сокращённо ICANN
> (читается айкэ́н) — международная некоммерческая организация,
> созданная 18 сентября 1998 года при участии правительства США для
> регулирования вопросов, связанных с доменными именами, IP-адресами и
> прочими аспектами функционирования Интернета.

[Wikipedia про ICANN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN)

Comment: А чисто в теории, то что регистратор не соблюдает это правило, это возможно?